# Permission denied (publickey) -- Strange error

Tags: 18.04, permissions, ssh, sshd

Thanks for looking! I need help with an issue that I am sure is trivial but it has me befuddled :-(.

Let me start by saying

1. I am not trying to establish public key/private key trust based password-less authentication.
2. This is my home network that consists of 5 ubuntu boxes, and I am having the same issue in connecting to/from all of them.

Here is the issue:
Recently, I made some changes to my network - swapped out an older wifi router for a newer mesh based router, added another network switch, also upgraded some boxes from older to latest LTS ubuntu version 18.04. Before this upgrade, I usually ssh'ed from one box to another using hostname/password to connect and do routine maintenance. But when I sat down to do this today (first time after all above said upgrades), I am hitting issues. Initially, it gave me the warning about the "man in the middle attack", which I was expecting with the router and switch changes. But after doing a

```
ssh-keygen -f "/home/machineA/.ssh/known_hosts" -R machineB
```

I am still seeing this message now when I am trying to ssh into machineB

`me@machineA:~/.ssh$ ssh myson@machineB
Permission denied (publickey).`

What I have tried so far:
I modified the /etc/ssh/sshd_config and changed

 `- PermitRootLogin prohibit-password to PermitRootLogin yes
 - PasswordAuthentication no to PasswordAuthentication yes`

on both machineA and machineB, no change. I also looked at prescribed permissions to the .ssh directory and its content, they look ok to me. for reference, on machineA, they are

```
drwx------  2 me me     4096 Jan  2 19:23 .ssh
```

and 

`-rw-r--r-- 1 me me  403 Oct  3  2018 id_rsa.pub
-rw------- 1 me me 1675 Oct  3  2018 id_rsa
-rw------- 1 me me 4833 Jan  2 18:56 known_hosts.old
-rw------- 1 me me 4833 Jan  2 19:23 known_hosts`

On machineB, they are

```
drwx------  2 myson myson    4096 Jan  2 20:13 .ssh
```

and

`myson@machineB:~/.ssh$ ls -lrt
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 myson myson 444 Jan  2 20:17 known_hosts`

Note that the id_rsa* files are missing from machineB, but I am assuming this is normal.

Finally, I am getting the same error in trying to ssh from machineB to machineA.

`myson@machineB:~/.ssh$ ssh me@machineA
Permission denied (publickey).`

Please let me know if there is any other information needed to debug this, I will be happy to provide.

And thanks again for looking to help!

Comment: I'm not sure why you say that you are not trying to create key-based authentication...since that IS exactly what you are indeed doing. If that was not your intent, then stop generating and copying keys.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. the key that you see in the listing of machineA is an old leftover from an exercise I did an year ago, it is no longer needed or used. I do not need key based auth since i need the ability to log in from any to any machine, too much work establishing trust based auth, or so i think.

Comment: Have you looked at your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file?  Make sure that `PubkeyAuthentication` is set to `no`.  If it is set to `yes` then the `id_rsa.pub` is needed on the client side.  Also, anytime you make any changes to the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file that you restart the service for it to take effect.  `systemctl restart sshd.service`

Answer (score 0):

So if i understand you correct you have ran the `ssh-keygen` command on all 5 machines then they should all have `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub` in the current user's `.ssh` folder (`ls ~/.ssh/`).

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 me me  403 Oct  3  2018 id_rsa.pub
-rw------- 1 me me 1675 Oct  3  2018 id_rsa
```

This means you have created a Private/Public key pair **for that user**, from this point the easiest thing to do is to gather the public key from the `id_rsa.pub` file on each machine and create a single `authorized_keys` file.

Once the file is populated with all 5 public keys, **one key per line** (makesure no line break) then put the `authorized_keys` file in the `.ssh` folder for user.

That should be it for SSH to work with SSHKey, Example:

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GC32O.png)
[image: Image 1]

Take note of the permission on the `authorized_keys` folder it is important.  Below is the less complicated article i can find at this time that goes over the steps.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-ssh-keys-on-ubuntu-1604

PS: Article  is 16.04 but it should still work for your 18.04.

Comment: thanks for replying, but my objective is NOT to establish public key/private key trust based password-less authentication, as mentioned in my OP. The ssh-keygen command was run only to remove ("-R machineB") the knowledge of machineB from machineA as I explained above. Or am I missing something here???

Comment: Sorry.... I think i finally got it.  You want it to prompt for password?

Comment: It that's what you want to do you can just rename the `sshd_config` file to something  and reinstall openssh to create default config file, `sudo apt install --reinstall openssh-server`. But be very carefully once you delete file, if it doesn't get created and you lose connection NO SSH.